# Button not showing up in simple android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a simple Android application to toggle between silent and normal profile settings. I am learning android development and this program comes from Android Application Development for Dummies. 
Here's the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >


    <ImageView 
        android:id ="@+id/phone_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_on"
        />    

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/toggle_silent_mode"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for `MainActivity.java`:
    package com.example.silentmodetoggle;

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);      

        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        setButtonClickListener();       
    }

    private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() 
    {
        int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
        if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        else
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
    }

    private void setButtonClickListener() 
    {
        Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                if (mPhoneIsSilent)
                {
                  mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                }
                else
                {
                        mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                }

                toggleUi();             
            }   
        } );    
    }

    private void toggleUi()
    {
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        Drawable newPhoneImage;

        if (mPhoneIsSilent)
            newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);
        else
            newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);

        imageview.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);  
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        toggleUi();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the `togglebutton` is not visible when I run the application. Also if I change the profile of to silent and then to normal, only image shows in the application (which belongs to the condition when

> mPhoneIsSilent = false.

Can anyone explain what's missing ?

Comment: try giving weight to both ImageView and Button..If the image is big, it will hide the button..

Comment: Is the button visible in the XML file? (Graphical layout).

Comment: @Bigflow: yes, the button is visibile in xml file

Comment: @ngesh: i gave weight to both, giving more weight to button. nothing changed

Comment: @rajatt.jainn .. give **layout_height="0dp"** for both of them.. and assign equal weight

Comment: give `android:weight="1"` to `ImageView`

Comment: @ngesh: yes, that did it. Can you explain what happened ?

Comment: your image size may be too large and it is wrap_content so it must be covering all the area.